# Application received signal SIGSEGV (IOS5)

Tags: ios, crash

it shows error log as below, who can tell me how could I find the code where induce this crash? thanks.

my device is iphone IOS 5.0,thanks very much.

```
(null)
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x353aa8a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x37751259 objc_exception_throw + 32

    2   CoreFoundation                      0x353aa789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 0

    3   CoreFoundation                      0x353aa7ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 34

    4   MMBang                              0x0018ccd9 MMBang + 1621209

    5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x327b67e3 _sigtramp + 38

    6   MMBang                              0x000e9bc1 MMBang + 953281

    7   CoreFoundation                      0x353043fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52

    8   MMBang                              0x00094ed5 MMBang + 605909

    9   CoreFoundation                      0x353043fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
    10  MMBang                              0x00093e6d MMBang + 601709
    11  MMBang                              0x00122ed3 MMBang + 1187539
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x353091fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 42
    13  Foundation                          0x34ecd747 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 350
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x3537ead3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x3537e29f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 214
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x3537d045 __CFRunLoopRun + 652
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x353004a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x3530036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x36f9c439 GSEventRunModal + 136
    20  UIKit                               0x32e0ccd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080

    21  MMBang                              0x0002a583 MMBang + 169347

    22  MMBang                              0x00003810 MMBang + 10256
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to breakpoints tab on xcode, in the bottom left hand corner there is a little plus button. Press it, click add exception breakpoint. Don't change any of the breakpoint settings and click done.

If you run your program again it should break on the line of code witch is crashing. As long as it is your code thats coursing this rather then an incorrect outlet in IB.

Hope this helps

Sam

Comment: but it does not happen every time, I only got this error log? how to know the reproduce procedure by analyzing this err log?

Comment: Well only you know that because we don't know how your app works the only way to repeat this issue is to try and follow the same procedures until the crash happens, I would also recommend enabling zombies to locate deallocated objects that are being referenced that can often be the reason for random crashes.